# How to define unique options for multiple instances of Splide

Tags: javascript, arrays, splidejs

I have a task at work that I've been struggling with. I'm supposed to use SplideJS to implement sliders. I'm not familiar with TypeScript (which SplideJS is written in) and my understanding of JS is basic. So I've been doing a lot of on the spot learning.

I am attempting to set up options for a large variety of different potential instances of Splide. There are ~20+ different potential variations that I need to assign to the correct instance of splide. I've set up a function that creates an array to push different versions of an object into. The function checks for a class name and adds the required key and value to the object. It is then supposed to push the object into the array then repeat the process. By the end, I should have an array filled with an object that has unique values.

What I'm getting, is an array filled with objects that each match the last defined object.

Issue: I don't have a good understanding of objects, so I'm not sure if I can manipulate an object, push it to an array and it saves a 'snapshot' of the object as a value in the array. If I then manipulate the same object again and push it to the next place in the array will the values in array[0] then be what I placed in array[1]? This is what I think is happening.

In order to achieve what I'm trying to do, do I need to create multiple objects? If I do, would a constructor function be the best path for me to take?

I've included a portion of my code below, just in case it'll help.

```
/* Function determines which set of splide options to use and what values to assign to each options object */

    function chooseOptions(){
    const splideCardOptions = {
            arrows: false,
            type: 'slide',
            mediaQuery: 'min',
            gap : '2rem',
            start: 0,
        };
        
        let moduleOptions = [];
        let sliderModules = document.querySelectorAll(".splide");

        sliderModules.forEach(module => {
            /* Card options */
            if(module.className.includes("card-splide")){

                
                
                    if(module.className.includes("small")){ /* Small card options */

                        splideCardOptions["perPage"] = 2;
                        splideCardOptions["breakpoints"]={
                            480 : { perPage : 3 },
                            768 : { 
                                perPage : 4,
                                gap : '3rem' 
                            },
                            1000 : { perPage : 5 }
                        };

                    }else if(module.className.includes("medium")){ /* Medium card options */

                        splideCardOptions["perPage"] = 2;
                        splideCardOptions["breakpoints"]={ 
                            768 : { 
                                perPage : 3,
                                gap : '3rem' 
                            },
                            1000 : { perPage : 4 },

                        };

                    }else if(module.className.includes("large")){ /* Large card options */

                        splideCardOptions["perPage"] = 1;
                        splideCardOptions["breakpoints"]={
                            480 : { perPage : 2 }, 
                            768 : { gap : '3rem'}, 
                            1000 : { perPage : 3 },
                        };

                    }else if(module.className.includes("extra")){ /* Extra card options */

                        splideCardOptions["perPage"] = 1;
                        splideCardOptions["breakpoints"]={
                            768 : {
                                perPage:2, 
                                gap: '3rem'
                            }, 
                        };
                    }
                    
                    //Breakpoints
                    /*if(module.className.includes("mobile-card-splide")){
                        splideCardOptions["breakpoints"][768]['destroy']=true;

                    }else if(module.className.includes("tablet-card-splide")){
                        splideCardOptions["breakpoints"][1000]['destroy']=true;

                    }else if(module.className.includes("laptop-card-splide")){
                        splideCardOptions["breakpoints"][1300]['destroy']=true;
                        
                    }*/
                    moduleOptions.push(splideCardOptions);
            

            }
```

[UPDATE]: I have managed to dynamically create objects using a for loop. So now my array of Splide options is accurate, but I haven't been able to attach them to their appropriate instance of Splide yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can move the Splide properties to separate functions. Here is an example with two different carousels, you can apply this to as many Splide carousels as you wish:

```
const splideCarouselMain = new Splide("#divSplideMain", MainSplideProperties());
const splideCarouselSecond = new Splide("#divSplideSecond", SecondSplideProperties());

splideCarouselMain.mount();
splideCarouselSecond.mount();

function MainSplideProperties()
{
    return {
        type: "loop"
    }
}

function SecondSplideProperties()
{
    return {
        pagination: false
    }
}
```

Of course you can implemented the above inside a forEach and multiple splide carousels can use the same function.